# VBA Script equivalent of Ctrl + Shift + End

Tags: excel, vba

Good evening. I am having trouble with this code below. The macro suddenly stops on that line. Does someone know what seems to be the problem?

```
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Range` object doesn't have an `ActiveCell` property. It should just be:

```
OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Copy
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably events are disabled so make sure that they are enabled.
Open the code window then "CTRL + G" then in the Immediate window type

```
Application.EnableEvents=True
```

then hit enter.

some code or macros may have been disabled/crashed events. So if problem occurs due to events, that should fix it.